# Two different but identically named elements in jaxb

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am trying to use `JAXB` to parse the following `XML`. I removed irrelevant parts. Unfortunately the original `XML` is generated by a third party application and I do not have the `DTD` or an `XSD` file available, so I am building my `JAXB` code by hand.

```
<add>
  <add-attr attr-name="UserName">
    <value type="string">User1</value>
  </add-attr>
  <add-attr attr-name="Name">
    <value type="structured">
      <component name="familyName">Doe</component>
      <component name="givenName">John</component>
    </value>
  </add-attr>
</add>
```

The problem is of course the `<value>` element. This can be a element with plain text, or if its attribute type is "structured, a list of `<component>` elements.

I have created two classes (value1 and value2) which implement the two options, but I cannot tell `JAXB` which one to use, because the elements are both named "value". Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option #1 - One Value Class**

You could have one `Value` class that includes a `String` property annotated with `@XmlMixed`.

```
package forum13232991;

import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Value {

    @XmlAttribute
    String type;

    @XmlMixed
    List<String> value;

    @XmlElement(name="component")
    List<Component> components;

}
```

**Option #2 - Multiple value Classes Via `XmlAdapter`**

If you want them to be separate classes you could leverage an `XmlAdapter` for this:

***ValueAdapter***

```
package forum13232991;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class ValueAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Value, Object> {

    @Override
    public Value marshal(Object object) throws Exception {
        Value value = new Value();
        if(object instanceof StructuredValue) {
            StructuredValue structuredValue = (StructuredValue) object;
            value.type = "structured";
            value.components = structuredValue.components;
        } else {
            StringValue stringValue = (StringValue) object;
            value.value.add(stringValue.value);
        }
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public Object unmarshal(Value value) throws Exception {
        if("string".equals(value.type)) {
            StringValue stringValue = new StringValue();
            StringBuilder strBldr = new StringBuilder();
            for(String string : value.value) {
                strBldr.append(string);
            }
            stringValue.value = strBldr.toString();
            return stringValue;
        } else {
            StructuredValue structuredValue = new StructuredValue();
            structuredValue.components = value.components;
            return structuredValue;
        }
    }

}
```

***AddAttr***

```
package forum13232991;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

public class AddAttr {

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(ValueAdapter.class)
    Object value;

}
```

***For More Information***

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/01/jaxb-and-inhertiance-using-xmladapter.html

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to create an XSL transformation which added an xsi:type attribute to the value elements based on the type attribute.  All your Value elements could then extend from the same BaseValue class and the add-attr element could have a reference to this BaseValue.

Comment: +1 - You could also use a SAX `XmlFilter` to add the `xsi:type` attribute: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/11/applying-namespace-during-jaxb-unmarshal.html